# Simply connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible

Tags: analysis

By Riemann mapping theorem, we know that every simply connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible. But I wonder if there exists a proof which doesn't use the Riemann mapping theorem (it's too high-leveled...)?

Comment: Yes. See the answers by Putman and Mosher here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18454/fundamental-groups-of-noncompact-surfaces. Once these results are proven it remains to note that each simply connected graph is contractible.